# String to array

Tags: iphone

I want to show the below value on the view it came in string.

Criteria==============(

```
"Communication skills",
"Open to following directions",
"Prepared for your case",
"Ability to obtain resolution",
"Willingness to work the process"
```

)

Criteria is the string value coming from web service

Comment: can u please elaborate your question a little to make understanding better for others to answer your question.

Comment: i just want to show these criteria values on the view...

Comment: So criteria is an array which contain list of string right?

Comment: are you trying to create an array from these strings?

Comment: @Dilip Criteria is string which contain the array...

Comment: You want to separate  all values in ""? Or store in array at index 0, 1, 2...

Comment: @Durgaprasad store into an array...

Comment: you want to strore array into string or string into array?

Comment: is your data in json format?

Comment: @sunny String into array...

Comment: @dilip yes in json format

Comment: Use SBJson library to parse json response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use SBJson library to parse json response

```
#import "SBJson.h"

NSString * criteria = @"Criteria:("Communication skills","Open to following directions","Prepared for your case","Ability to obtain resolution","Willingness to work the process")";           

//criteria is your json response or whatever else is your response.

SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
NSDictionary *jsonData = (NSDictionary *) [jsonParser objectWithString:criteria error:nil];

NSArray *criteriaAry = [[NSArray alloc]init];
criteriaAry= [jsonData objectForKey:@"Criteria"];
```

Answer (score 2):

try like this,if your string is

```
criteria=(
"Communication skills",
"Open to following directions",
"Prepared for your case",
"Ability to obtain resolution",
"Willingness to work the process"
)
then try like this,

 criteria=[criteria stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];

 NSArray *resultArray=[criteria componentsSeparatedByString:@","];//String to Atrray
```

Comment: @Verma:check second line .

Answer (score 1):

if you wants convert array to string try this code

```
NSArray *st=[yourstring componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Answer (score 1):

to add items in "" from string into array use

```
NSString *str = @" 'Communication skills','Willingness to work the process'";
NSArray * arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSLog(@"%@",arr);
```